# Running Batch in Execute Anonymous but throwing error: method does not exist or incorrect signature void format string from the type anon

Tags: apex, batch, execute-anonymous

I need to run a scheduled batch out of schedule. It has been working every day perfectly for months.

I went to try to run it in Execute Anonymous but I get the error:
Method does not exist or incorrect signature void format string from the type anon

```
Id batchJobId = Database.executeBatch(Update_IC_CampaignBatch(),200);
system.debug(' \n SEAN DEBUG = '+batchJobId);
```

This is the batch:

```
GLOBAL CLASS Update_IC_CampaignBatch implements Database.Batchable <SObject> {
    GLOBAL Database.queryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext ctx) {
        String lsStatus = 'ICReady';
        string query = 'SELECT id,Name from Lead WHERE status=:lsStatus'  ;
        RETURN database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    GLOBAL VOID execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List <Lead> scope) {
        Set<ID> leadIDs= new Set<ID>();
        for(Lead l: scope){
            leadIDs.add(l.id);
        }
        system.debug('LeadIDs===>'+LeadIDs);
        Set<ID> campaignIDs = new Set<ID>();
        for(CampaignMember cm : [SELECT CampaignID, LeadID, Status FROM CampaignMember WHERE LeadID IN : leadIDs]){
            campaignIDs.add(cm.CampaignID);
        }

        list<Campaign> listCampaign = new list<Campaign>();
        for(Campaign c : [select Id, Status, Name, Parent.Name from Campaign where Id IN : campaignIDs ]){
            if(c.Name.left(11) == 'IC Campaign'){
                c.Status = 'IC Daily Campaign Ready';
            }
            else{
                c.Status = c.Parent.Name + ' Campaign Ready';
            }
            listCampaign.add(c);
        }
        update listCampaign;
    }

    GLOBAL VOID finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing to create the instance of the class using `new` keyword.

```
Id batchJobId = Database.executeBatch(Update_IC_CampaignBatch(),200); // missing new
```

It should be:

```
Id batchJobId = Database.executeBatch(new Update_IC_CampaignBatch(),200);
```

Answer (score 1):

Update_IC_CampaignBatch batch1 = new Update_IC_CampaignBatch();
Database.executeBatch(batch1);

Comment: While this does provide an answer but you may like to add more details to this highlighting the original issue vs. how to fix this.

Comment: Sorry for a loosely typed answer. I'm new in this form, but I got the point. Thanks for the tip.